# Is it permitted to use 2 content providers per application?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

It's out of requirement of working on existing code base. Now I need to add my existing code to it. Basically its like merging 2 huge code bases, both having one content provider each.

Is it possible to have both workin together. When I tried, it crashed. But when i run it with just one at-a-time, it runs properly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `It crashed`, what did the Logcat say in that case.